# Query external database with rails. Abstract Class + establish_connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, mysql2

I am trying to establish a connection to an external CRM database (MySQL) in my rails4 app. I am able to connect to the DB through console, and i can use the MySQL2 gem to directly connect and query using this approach:

```
connection = Mysql2::Client.new(host:11.12.14.14,username...)
results = connection.query("SELECT * FROM.....")
```

However, I am confused as to how best to implement and reuse this connection. I have concerns about connection pooling and opening too many connections... Through researching this topic I found a lot of information about using a model... So I setup an abstract Model, and put the database connection info in my database.yml

```
class ExternalCrm < ActiveRecord::Base
  # No corresponding table in the DB.
  self.abstract_class = true

  establish_connection(:external_crm)

  def self.getCustomerId(first_name, last_name)
    get = connection.select_one("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE First_Name=#{connection.quote(first_name)} AND Last_Name=#{connection.quote(last_name)}")
    get.id
  end

end
```

This works... and i can run this method BUT why do i have to call the connection ExternalCrm.connection.select_one() rather than just directly saying ExternalCrm.find_by_sql()... also, will calling connection every time use the pool or could it cause a too many connections issue?

Most of the queries I need to run are just big raw SQL statements, so i don't really need activerecord, and models for each table. So I am not sure if using an abstract model is the best approach here...

My goal is to establish the connection, and then be able to run methods the connection... for example **ExternalCrm.getUserId(firstname,lastname)**

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Reusing connection.

You have already wrapped up in a class, hence a connection will remain open all the time and it's a good approach, and the problem of multiple connections not to be worried.

---

You haven't specified if you are dealing with multiple table tables with `ExternalCrm` connection, if not

```
self.table_name = 'customers'
```

would be good then access class with ease `ExternalCrm` for using any methods., like,

```
ExternalCrm.getUserId(firstname,lastname)
```

In case if tables are changing you could propably reset every connection is completed with the **table** interaction,
with

> [reset_column_information](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reset_column_information/class)

method.

Check my [blog](http://imnithin.github.io/multiple-database.html) for more.

Comment: I will be dealing with multiple tables, BUT I don't need multiple models, I will build the joins myself and just need to use my own raw queries on the database. I already have all my complex queries written.... For example (simple for demostration): "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Last_Name='Smith' AND First_Name='John'" --- Is there a way to not specify a table name and just use raw SQL queries? As I said in my post **Most of the queries I need to run are just big raw SQL statements, so i don't really need activerecord, and models for each table.**

Comment: @JoelGrannas `connection.select_all(query)` must run your any sort of query I believe, dealing with multiple tables I have said it above, how to go with.